# NumPy linalg.eig

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

I have this annoying problem and I haven't figured it out yet. I have a matrix and I want to find the eigenvectors, so I write:

```
val,vec = np.linalg.eig(mymatrix)
```

and then I got vec . My problem is when others from my group do the same with the same matrix (mymatrix) we dont get the same eigenvectors !!

Someone who can put up an explanation?

Comment: How different are the outputs? Can you provide an example?

Comment: It's almost the same, but the numbers are different.

Comment: could you be a bit more quantitative? Are we talking about errors near the floating point precision of your machine? Please post the outputs for a simple (small) test case that illustrates your problem. This will make it easier to help answer your question.

Comment: for example I get something like: array([[-4.4, 6.6, -1.7], [7.1, 7.8, -2,9], [-9.8, 2.3, -1.4]])

And they:
array([[4.4, -6.6, 1.7], [7.1, 7.8, -2,9], [-9.8, 2.3, -1.4]])

So some of my result is the same, but the first in my output is multiplicated with -1

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental property of an eigenvector `x` is

```
A x = lambda x
```

for some constant `lambda`.

If `x` is an eigenvector, so is `-x`:

```
A (-x) = - A x = - lambda x = lambda (-x)
```

---

Note also that the set of eigenvectors may not be unique. For example, any vector (of the appropriate dimension) can be an eigenvector of the identity matrix.

[`np.linalg.eig`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) tries to return a set of eigenvectors, but does not guarantee a particular, unique set.

Comment: Thank you! can I do something with my code, so I can get a different output? Or do I have to live with my computer chose to calculate the eigenvectors?

Comment: You have to live with what your computer chooses.

Comment: @Guest: If you want a unique representation of the eigenspaces of your matrix, you could compute the [Grassmann coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding) of each eigenspace (but this is probably well beyond the scope of this forum).