# PCA from scratch and Sklearn PCA giving different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to implement PCA from scratch. Following is the code:

```
sc = StandardScaler()  #standardization
X_new = sc.fit_transform(X)
Z = np.divide(np.dot(X_new.T,X_new),X_new.shape[0])  #covariance matrix
eig_values, eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(Z)           #eigen vectors calculation 
eigval_sorted = np.sort(eig_values)[::-1]             
ev_index  =np.argsort(eigval_sorted)[::-1]
pc = eig_vectors[:,ev_index]                         #eigen vectors sorts on the basis of eigen values
W = pc[:,0:2]                                        #extracting 2 components
print(W)
```

and getting the following components:

```
[[ 0.52237162 -0.37231836]
[-0.26335492 -0.92555649]
[ 0.58125401 -0.02109478]
[ 0.56561105 -0.06541577]]
```

When I use the sklearn's PCA I get the following two components:

```
array([[ 0.52237162, -0.26335492,  0.58125401,  0.56561105],
       [ 0.37231836,  0.92555649,  0.02109478,  0.06541577]])
```

Projection onto new feature space gives following different figures:

[image: PCA from scratch]

[image: Sklearn PCA]

Where am I doing it wrong and what can be done to resolve the problem?

Comment: Could you try calculating the covariance matrix like this `cov_matrix = np.cov(X_new)`?  Also please include a sample of `X`.

Comment: Those are exactly the same components but transposed. What am I missing?

Comment: @felice there is a sign difference as far as 2nd column is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a PCA are technically not n vectors, but a subspace of dimension n. This subspace is represented by n vectors that span that subspace.

In your case, while the vectors are different, the spanned subspace is the same, so the result of the PCA is the same.

If you want to align your solution perfectly with the sklearn solution, you need to normalise your solution in the same way. Apparently sklearn prefers positive values over negative values? You'd need to dig into their documentation.

---

edit:
Yes, of course, what I wrote is wrong. The algorithm itself returns ordered orthonormal basis vectors. So vectors that are of length one and orthogonal to each other and they are ordered in their 'importance' to the dataset. So way more information than just the subspace.

However, if v, w, u are a solution of the PCA, so should +/- v, w, u be.

---

edit: It seems that np.linalg.eig has no mechanism to guarantee it will also return the same set of eigenvectors representing the eigenspace, see also here:
[NumPy linalg.eig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464081/numpy-linalg-eig#5464711)

So, a new version of numpy, or just how the stars are aligned today, can change your result. Although, for a PCA it should only vary in +/-

Comment: Please check it here: https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_pca_in_3_steps.html#covariance-matrix

Comment: According to it, both the answers should be perfectly same.

Comment: Actually I am curious to know how to get the same output as shown in the provided link. The author has done nothing different from what I have done.

Comment: Yes, I understand, my comment was not helpful... Do you get the same covariance matrix as the author does?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same!

Comment: This person even states that the same software on different OS can return different eigenvectors (again just +/- since we normalise the vectors) https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/08/07/eigenvectors-not-unique.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing to it. Let me check it!